# Finding the class name of comment box in youtube videos for click() with selenium

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

We are trying to create comment bot for YouTube. However, we are unable to find a class name to click which we will paste the comment text, it is giving some errors. We tried these so far;

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='input-content' or @class='style-scope' or @class='paper-input-container']").click()
```

error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

and we tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('ytd-commentbox').click()
```

error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message:
```

How can we find the right class to click to post comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us analyze went wrong with our code and analyze the error. In the first attempt you are doing :

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='input-content' or @class='style-scope' or @class='paper-input-container']").click()
```

This gives an error as :

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

The reason is :

As you have used `find_elements`, it returns a **`List`**. Hence when you try to invoke **`click()`** method **`AttributeError`** is returned.

Next, you have tried :

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('ytd-commentbox').click()
```

Which produces an error as :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message:
```

The reason is :

As you have used **`find_element_by_class_name`**, it returned the very first match which is either not interact-able or have an overlay. Hence you see **`ElementNotInteractableException`** exception.

### Solution :

The comment box have an `id` as **`simplebox-placeholder`**. So we can use the `id` and induce **`ExplicitWait`** for the **`WebElement`** to be clickable as follows:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.ID,"simplebox-placeholder"))
element.send_keys("This is a comment")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, find_elements_by_xpath() returns list and click() is not applicable for list that's **the possible reason it is giving error**. Can you try following things ?

1. If you are sure there is only one such element which you want to click then use **find_element_by_xpath()** (not its element and **not** elements) and see if it works
2. Replace

   ```
   driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='input-content' or @class='style-scope' or @class='paper-input-container']").click()
   ```

   with (assuming only element is present need to click 0th element)

   ```
   driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='input-content' or @class='style-scope' or @class='paper-input-container']")[0].click()
   ```
3. Use WebDriverWait which will wait until element is clickable for 20
   seconds by polling mechanism

   ```
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

   element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
   "//*[@class='input-content' or @class='style-scope' or
   @class='paper-input-container']")))

   element.click()
   ```

Comment: The problem is I'm not even sure to use these classes I just used "inspect" to locate comment box and choosed classes from the list. I tried what you suggested and it gives an error:

IndexError: list index out of range

I found something similart to what I'm trying to do on github. He used:

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='comment-section-renderer']/div/div[2]/div").click()

But it is not working too because there is no such element called comment-section-renderer anymore.

Comment: @Soner  Okay that means with XPATH you have provided driver could not find element. This could be potentially due to wrong XPATH or element is not visible instantly. I would suggest use chrome and inspect element and go to copy and copy xpath and check if it works for you. Also try if WebDriverWait as shown above works or not.

Comment: It gave me this: driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='textarea']").click()

And when I used it I got an error:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

Comment: don't call click() just `print driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='textarea']")` and check if it is printing any objects in list or not.

Comment: It printed only this: []

Comment: This means XPATH is wrong, can we take this to chat after couple of hours ?

Comment: Thank you :) It would be great